# Python ruamel doesnt preserve format for newline in yaml

Tags: python, yaml, newline, indentation, ruamel.yaml

My original yaml file contains newlines after dash (-) that I want to preserve after I dump it

```
#  This is my yaml
color_1:
    blue: 
        -
# I want to preserve this newline after the dash
            width_1: "1"
            height_1: [1]
            size_1: 4
        -
            width_1: "2"
            height_2: [1,2,3,4]
            size_2: 4
```

My Code

```
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
yaml = YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
yaml.boolean_representation = ['False', 'True']
yaml.indent(mapping=4, sequence=3, offset=0)

def main():
    config_path = "my_yaml_before.yaml"
    config = yaml.load(open(config_path))
    yaml.dump(config, sys.stdout)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

After I run my script I see the dump file that has remove newline as below, also I notice that between the item of the list there is extra space that I also dont want to get

```
#  This is my yaml
color_1:
    blue:
# I want to preserve this newline after the dash
    -  width_1: "1"
       height_1: [1]
       size_1: 4
    -  width_1: "2"
       height_2: [1, 2, 3, 4]
       size_2: 4
```

Comment: I have added yaml.compact(seq_seq=False, seq_map=False)
this worked and new output preserve the newlines

Comment: looks like I should pay more attention to recent changes to the `ruamel.yaml` source code (in particular release 0.15.73)

Comment: @saler011 hello. I know this is an old thread but adding `compact` didn't work for me to preserve the newline. Maybe I added it in the wrong place? Where in your script did you use it, because for me it doesn't change anything.